# WinJS: use a XPath method with a responseXML object

Tags: xpath, windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

I have a problem with a Windows8 application. Here is the simplified portion of code:

```
return WinJS.xhr({ url: url }).then(function (response) {

    var response = response.responseXML;
    var element = response.selectSingleNode("COUNT(//item)");

    console.log(element);

}
```

However, it raises an error: `JavaScript runtime error: Unknown method. -->COUNT(//<--item`.

Is it possible to call some XPath methods  in WinJS? If so, where is the error? I guess it is not the correct method invoked (we select a scalar here, not a node). But I do not find anything in the documentation.

Comment: I am not familiar with winjs but as far as XPath is concerned the function name is `count` and not `COUNT`. However with other Microsoft XPath APIs like in MSXML or .NET a method like `selectSingleNode` does only work with XPath expression selecting a node or node-set, not with ones returning a primitive value. .NET has an Evaluate method for such XPath expressions, I don't know whether that is of any use in winjs. For your simple expression you could try `var count = response.selectNodes("//item").length;` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I did like you proposed finally. :)

Notice that there were some changes since Developer Preview 7, and _selectSingleNode_ has been replaced by _querySelectorAll_.